# Send and Receive text using sockets in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I do not have much familiarity with Delphi 2010 and am having trouble with using components ClientSocket and ServerSocket. The question is simple: I am trying to send a text from a client to a server using the following code:

```
cliente.Socket.SendText('call');
```

On the server side I writed the following code:

```
procedure TForm6.ServerClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
s: string;
begin
s:=Socket.ReceiveText;
if s = 'call' then
begin
showmessage('Client is Calling');
end;
end;
```

However, the server dont displaying the message. Could help me once more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In D2009+, `SendText()` and `ReceiveText()` do not work correctly with Unicode strings.  It is better to use `SendBuf()` and `ReceiveBuf()` directly instead.

With that said, `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` have been deprecated for a LONG time.  You should use a different component set, such as Indy (which also ships with Delphi), eg:

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('call');
```

```
procedure TForm6.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  if s = 'call' then
  begin
    // TIdTCPServer is a multi-threaded component,
    // but ShowMessage() is not thread-safe...
    Windows.MessageBox(0, 'Client is Calling', '', MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's really, the sockets are deprecated for a long time, but I did not know how to use another component to the same result, but now I know. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway for those who are still using the sokets in Delphi 2010 a function that responds to the initial question:`function ReturnStringReceive(Socket: TCustomWinSocket): String;
Var Res: AnsiString;
Begin
SetLength(res, Socket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(nil)^, -1));
SetLength(res, Socket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(res)^, Length(res)));
Result := String(res);
End;` and to call: `procedure TForm9.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
label1.caption := ReturnStringReceive(Socket);
end;`

Comment: @V.Salles: that is not a true solution, because it does not take message boundaries into account. Imagine what would happen if you called `SendText()` multiple times before `ReturnStringReceive()` is called. `ReceiveBuf(nil, -1)` (which is the same as `ReceiveLength()`) is likely to return a value that includes data from more than one `SendText()`.

Comment: @V.Salles: the *correct* way to handle this is to either: 1) preceed each string with its length, so the receiver can read the length first and then read the data, or 2) delimit the messages with a unique identifier not found in the string data, so the receiver can keep reading until it finds the delimiter.